# do I need to add submodule folder into .gitignore?

Tags: git

First, the folder `libs` is not a submodule, we just copy it from other directory, and put it into `.gitignore`, then we submodule-ed `libs`, do I need to remove `libs` from `.gitignore` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git submodule is smart enough to understand the directory is a submodule and automatically ignores it in the right contexts.

It's probably not necessary for you to remove it from .gitignore, because it will be ignored anyway. On the other hand, it's no longer needed in .gitignore, so you may as well remove it. It should function the same either way, but I would suggest removing it (it seems more tidy and correct).